# Jquery removing issue divs still remains

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Yesterday I coded a Commentbox in PHP, HTML and ajax. The ajax part gives me the opportunity to delete a comment without refreshing the page. The way I do this, is that I give each and every comment (div) a unique id via the database. So let us for example say that in my mysql database this is how a comment looks like:

```
Username: blabla<br>
Comment: haha this is so funny<br>
id: 52
```

This will be printed out in the html page likes this for example:

```
<div class="commentStyle" id="<?php echo $commentid; ?>">
This comment will now have the id of 52
<div class="deleteComment">Delete the comment here!</div>
</div>
```

AND THEN!

Comes the ajax part which is coded something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".deleteComment").click(function(){


 //Getting the id of comment

 id = $(".deleteComment").attr("id");

$.ajax{

Type: 'GET',
url: 'deletecomment.php',
data: "id=" + id,
success: function(){

 $("#" + id).hide();

 }


 }

});

});
```

This works fine when deleting the first comment. But it WONT LET ME DELETE OTHER COMMENTS UNLESS I REFRESH THE PAGE >.<. The first comment can be perfectly deleted without refreshing the page, but when I want to delete other comments I have to refresh the page multiple times.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Surely you mean `$(this).parent().attr("id")`?

Comment: there is missing '(' after the $.ajax.

Comment: Im sorry guys. The code is very messy here, but the syntax is correct in my document. The function is working, but the problem is that its deleting only one comment.

Comment: `Variable id is without var keyword, which makes it Global`. Its bad idea to pollute global namespace for no good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your document ready event would work properly only for the first click. In order to get this work, you must have an on click event registered within the tag.
Example :

```
<div class="deleteComment" onclick="DeleteMe(id)">Delete the comment here!</div>
</div>

function DeleteMe(id)
{
  $.ajax{

          Type: 'GET',
          url: 'deletecomment.php',
          data: "id=" + id,
          success: function(){

               $("#" + id).hide();

           }


          }

        });
  }
```

If the on click on a div does not work, you can use an anchor tag (Delete here) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`.deleteComment` is **child** of `<div class="commentStyle"..`, so you can select it with [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector:

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

Or more specifically:

```
var id = $(this).parent('.commentStyle').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to get the id from the parent element first and then target the child, the element you clicked, to hide the comment from it after the ajax request returns success:

```
$(".deleteComment").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var child = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'deletecomment.php',
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(){
            child.hide();
            // or if you want to delete the entire element with the id of X
            // child.parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes which need to be done in your code.

First of all add ID tag to the inner div.

```
<div class="commentStyle" id="<?php echo $commentid; ?>">
This comment will now have the id of 52
<div class="deleteComment" id="<?php echo $commentid; ?>">Delete the comment here!  </div>
</div>
```

Secondly use *this*

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
```

instead of...

```
id = $(".deleteComment").attr("id");
```

Thirdly change the ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
        Type: 'GET',
        url: 'deletecomment.php',
        data: "id=" + id
    }).done(function(){
        $("#" + id).hide();
    });
```

Hope this works for you, if not just reply me.